# Add a title page to birkjour class

Tags: formatting

For some reason a journal I am submitting a paper to sent back my manuscript because I need to add a "title page."  My understanding is I'm supposed to submit said "manuscript" in .tex format using their birkjour class so needless to say I'm at a loss to figure out exactly how to add the title page without ruining the subsequent formatting.

The problem I have is if I use \newpage, then for some reason the subsequent pages are all shifted down by about 3 inches.  The code is below:

```
\documentclass{birkjour}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,mathtools}
%\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{url, hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\usepackage{diagrams}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}


\begin{document}

\newpage 
\noindent Title Page Here

\newpage

\title[Annoyed]{This is really annoying}
\author[Doe]{John Doe}
\address{Annoying Road\\ University of Annoyed People}
\email{doe@annoyedpeople.edu}
\date{\today}

\keywords{Title pages}

\begin{abstract} 
In this paper, we try to figure out how to add a title page to our manuscript without entirely messing up the subsequent pages.     
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.  Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.  Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.  Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.  Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.

Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.

Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.

Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.

Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue.

Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. Continue reading to see the vertical space issue. 


\end{document}
```

Notice how on page 3, there's a huge swatch of entirely unnecessary vertical space that wouldn't be there if it weren't for the \newpage.

If \newpage doesn't work with birkjour, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you download `birkjour.zip` from 
https://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/download?SGWID=0-40465-0-0-0

the download includes a PDF describing how to use it.

In your example you are doing most of the right things, but in the wrong order.